# Neovim Connect DAP to Project Running in Docker

Tags: debugging, neovim

Is there a way to configure the nvim-dap dotnet setup to connect netcoredbg to an app running in a docker container? I've already followed the steps listed in the nvim-dap installation page: https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap/wiki/Debug-Adapter-installation#dotnet, so my setup looks similar to this:

```
dap.adapters.coreclr = {
  type = 'executable',
  command = '/path/to/dotnet/netcoredbg/netcoredbg',
  args = {'--interpreter=vscode'}
}
dap.configurations.cs = {
  {
    type = "coreclr",
    name = "launch - netcoredbg",
    request = "launch",
    program = function()
        return vim.fn.input('Path to dll ', vim.fn.getcwd() .. '/bin/Debug/', 'file')
    end,
  },
}
```

The path for the program to debug will need to be changed, but I'm not too sure what to change it too. I also think editing the adapter args or the cs configuration request to "attach" instead of "launch" may be necessary for it to connect to a docker container process.